Is this inline asm correct for bitcasting int as float?
I am trying to familiarise myself with gnu inline assembly. I wrote a single line inline asm to reinterpret int as float. While this prints the correct result, I am wondering whether this is correct.
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    int x = 0x80000000; // -0.0
    float y;
    asm("vmovd %0, %%xmm0"
     : "=r"(y)
     : "r"(x));
    printf("%f\n", y); 
}

I am a beginner in assembly.

Just for the record, inline asm is a bad way to type-pun aka bit_cast except as a learning exercise for inline asm syntax. Just use memcpy.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).
And if you do use inline asm, generally don't write your own move instructions; use the power of operand constraints to tell the compiler where you want the input and where your asm leave the output, and let it invent the data movement.


I am wondering whether this is correct.

No, "=r" lets the compiler pick its choice of any integer register for that output operand, which will vary depending on the surrounding code and optimization options.  You're writing XMM0 without having told the compiler about it through an operand or clobber.
%0 is the first operand, the output "=r", and you're using it as the source for vmovd.  (This is AT&T syntax, so destination is on the right.)  So it' actually %1 (the source operand) you aren't referencing.  The compiler will often pick the same GPR for an input and output operand (if you don't specify "=&r" to make an early-clobber output, for cases where an output is written before the last time all inputs are read.)
If you put %0 and %1 in the format string, e.g. as a comment, you can look at the compiler's asm output and see what it picked for that operand.
float buggy_foo() {
    int x = 0x80000000; // -0.0
    float y;
    asm("vmovd %0, %%xmm0   # op0 picked %0  op1 picked %1"
     : "=r"(y)
     : "r"(x));
    return y;  // will be in XMM0 per the calling convention
}

From the asm output with GCC -O3 targeting Linux (on Godbolt):
buggy_foo:
    movl    $-2147483648, %eax    # materialize x in EAX
# from your asm statement
    vmovd %eax, %xmm0   # op0 was %eax  op1 was %eax
# end of your asm statement
    movd    %eax, %xmm0    # compiler-generated copy of y to retval reg (XMM0 for a float)
    ret

Keeping the function minimal reduces the noise we have to sift through to find exactly what GCC thought was necessary just for the asm statement itself.  return of a float in x86-64 needs it in an XMM register, and can use a float directly without needing to convert it to double like for printf.
If we compile your main using this asm statement, we see why it happened to work there, too, since x and y again pick the same register (EAX).
    movl    $-2147483648, %eax
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
 # from your asm statement.  I compiled without -march=x86-64-v3 so the compiler-generated insns are legacy-SSE
    vmovd %eax, %xmm0   # op0 was %eax  op1 was %eax

    movd    %eax, %xmm1  # compiler-generated

    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $1, %eax
    cvtss2sd        %xmm1, %xmm0   # this is why GCC used pxor to zero XMM0 earlier
    call    *printf@GOTPCREL(%rip)
   ...


You can do asm("" : "=rx"(y) : "0"(x)) to ask for the input in the same register as the output, and give the compiler a choice of integer (r) or vector (x) registers.   That's like "+r"(y) but allowing a different variable of a different type for the input half.
That avoids ever materializing the integer in an general-purpose integer register if the compiler doesn't think that's optimal.  FP constants are often just loaded from .rodata.
Although since GCC 12 or 13 or so, GCC has preferred mov-immediate to a GPR and vmovd plus vpbroadcastd for vector constants with duplicate elements, instead of loading them from static storage.  But for x as an input to an asm statement, even older GCC want to start with it in a GPR.
float matching_constraint() {
    int x = 0x80000000; // -0.0
    float y;
    asm(".space 0   # op0 was %0  op1 was %1"  // .space 0  is zero byte, only used to avoid Godbolt filtering comments.  Empty string would be fine.
     : "=x"(y)
     : "0"(x));
     // Older GCC: with just "=x", the "0" input is loaded from .rodata with movd
     // but with "=rx", it does mov-immediate + movd reg, xmm like newer GCC always wants to do
    return y;
}

With this, the compiler picked XMM0 for y (and thus also for x), and did a movd itself to get the value there.  Older GCC like GCC6 do a mov-immediate to a GPR, then store/reload to stack space, with the default -mtune, only using movd reg, xmm with -mtune=intel or a specific Intel like -mtune=haswell.  Using "=x" instead of "=rx" for some reason makes GCC6 do movd  .LC1(%rip), %xmm0, even though it still picks %xmm0 for the operand in both cases.
matching_constraint:
        movl    $-2147483648, %eax
        movd    %eax, %xmm0
        .space 0   # op0 was %xmm0  op1 was %xmm0
        ret

Again, .space 0 is just a zero-byte nop which is only there so I don't have to uncheck  "filter comments" on the Godbolt compiler explorer.  I could have used any GAS statement like .Ldummy=42  # comment to define a symbol, or .global main
I could have written asm("" : "=rx"(y) : "0"(x)); with the empty string as the template. For correctness at least, it doesn't matter what register the compiler picked (integer or XMM), because "0" guarantees that input will pick the same register as output operand 0.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html)

You could use register float y asm("xmm0"); to force "=r"(y) to pick XMM0 specifically if you want to hard-code a register name into the asm template, but usually better to let the compiler do register allocation.  In this case where you're passing it to printf, the x86-64 System V calling convention will indeed want it in XMM0.  Windows x64 would want it in XMM1 and EDX.
Except it needs a cvtss2sd anyway because variadic functions promote their float args to double so it doesn't matter what register the float is in, other than avoiding a false dependency (for performance reasons) by writing the same register it reads.  GCC is being silly here pxor-zeroing XMM0; if it had done movd %eax, %xmm0 ; cvtss2sd %xmm0, %xmm0, that would have an output dependency on the same register that's already an input dependency, making it a non-problem.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for more guides and useful Q&As.
The manual is also quite good these days: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html

Thanks for the detailed answer. It took me a while to understand the whole answer but it is worth it.

When programming in C, the best way is probably to type-pun through a union.

@fuz: That's valid, too, although I find the syntax can get cluttered especially if you're also accessing members of structs. And you have to put the union declaration somewhere.  If you're only doing one type-pun in the whole file, a single memcpy is nice and clean and easy.  It means the type-pun has to be a separate statement, not just part of a larger expression, which is both good for visibility if that's the main tricky thing happening, but also potentially bad if you'd rather write more compact code that's doing a lot of type-punning especially of multiple variables.

If you're using GNU extensions anyway, GCC has __builtin_bit_cast, but for some reason it's only available in C++ mode, where you should of course just use C++20 std::bit_cast instead of the raw builtin.   https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fbit_005fcast

@PeterCordes You can declare the union locally, so not polluting the file scope.

@fuz: Right, but then it takes up a line of the function, a longish line with a bunch of syntax going on.  If I see a memcpy(&dst, &src, sizeof(dst));, it's easy to recognize that as a type-pun (although you'd also use that for an unaligned or aliasing load or store, so I guess it could warrant a comment), without distracting me from the logic the function's actually trying to implement.  I guess you can declare and init a variable of the union type on the same line if you keep the member names very short so it's not too long for one line.

This isn't correct for a few reasons:

You assumed y is in xmm0 which isn't necessarily true.
You used %0 instead of %1 for the input.
You used the r contraint for y, but r is used for general-purpose registers, whereas x should be used for xmm registers.

The corrected code is:
asm("vmovd %1, %0"
 : "=x"(y)
 : "r"(x));

Note that this assumes you're on x86-64, and that vmovd requires AVX support (use movd otherwise).
